# How to configure a Great Expectations [Validation Result Store] to Snowflake

Tags: validation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, great-expectations

Is it possible for Great Expectations to configure Validation Result Store to Snowflake database? Found only variant for [PostgreSQL](https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/guides/setup/configuring_metadata_stores/how_to_configure_a_validation_result_store_to_postgresql/) in documentation. I mean here possibility to directly put validation result to behind the scenes created a new table by Great Expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done (got answer from SLACK GE channel) - I created in advance table (name as `ge_validations_store`) in the Database with the following

```
DLL:
         Column         |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default 
------------------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 expectation_suite_name | character varying |           | not null | 
 run_name               | character varying |           | not null | 
 run_time               | character varying |           | not null | 
 batch_identifier       | character varying |           | not null | 
 value                  | character varying |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "ge_validations_store_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (expectation_suite_name, run_name, run_time, batch_identifier)
```

And after that result were stored directly there.